# what can we say about continuity, differentiability of $f$ and denseness of $A$?

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

Define $$f:(0,1) \to (0,1)$$ 
such that $ \ f(x)=0 \ \forall x \in E \ $, where $E$ is subset of $(0,1)$, with all irrationals $ \in (0,1)$ and rationals with non terminating decimal expansion $ \in (0,1)$.

And $f(x) =  \frac{1}{10^n}$ when $x \in (0,1) \setminus E$
Where $n=$ number of non zero digits in decimal expansion of rational number in $(0,1) \setminus E$

On which subset of $(0,1)$ $ f $ is differentiable, what is set of discontinuities of $f$ ?
If $A = E \setminus Q^{c}$, is $A$ dense in $(0,1)$?
Please give me your valuable hint or suggestions, so that I can solve this question!

Comment: Maybe [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=differentiability+ruler+function) and [this survey](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/m9SfPUdr4I4) will help.

Comment: Thank you [Dave L. Renfro](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13130/dave-l-renfro) it is indeed helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is nowhere differentiable.

(I). $E$ is dense in $(0,1)$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x\in E.$ So if $y\in (0,1)$ and $f(y)\ne 0$ then $f$ is discontinuous at $y,$ and hence not differentiable at $y.$

(II). If $f(y)=0$ then $y\in E.$ Now, given $r>0,$ take $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ with $10^{-n}<r$ and $10^{-n}<\min(y,1-y).$ Since $y\in E$ there is a (unique) positive integer $m$ such that $m10^{-n}<y<(m+1)10^{-n}<1.$

For brevity let $a=m10^{-n}$ and $b=(m+1)10^{-n}.$

Since $f(a)\ge 10^{-n}\le f(b)$ and $f(y)=0,$ and $a<y<b,$ we have $$\frac {f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}<0<\frac {f(b)-f(y)}{b-y}.$$ But at least one of the far LHS or far RHS in the line above has an absolute value of at least $1,$ otherwise $$2\cdot 10^{-n}\le f(b)+f(a)=|f(b)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f(a)|=$$ $$=\frac {|f(b)-f(y)|}{|b-y|}(b-y)+\frac {|f(y)-f(a)|}{|y-a|}(y-a)<$$ $$< (b-y)+(y-a)=b-a=10^{-n},$$ which is absurd.

So  for any $r>0$ there exist $a,b \in (y-r,y+r)\cap (0,1)$ with $$\frac {f(b)-f(y)}{b-y}-\frac {f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}>1.$$